# Not understanding mocking in php or in guzzel.

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking

Looking for some help here. Consider the following class:

```
class Details {

    public function details($href) {
        $client = new Client();

        $response = $client->request('GET', $href);
        EveLogHandler::requestLog($response, 'eveonline_item_details.log');

        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Pretty basic, we create a client, send a GET request to the href, log the response, then do stuff on status code of 200 or return false.

What I dont get is the following:

1. How do you test this with out hitting the API?
2. How do you mock the client objects as demonstrated [here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/testing.html) inside a class method
3. What if this was a pool? How would you mock a pool? see example bellow:

In this example for Pool I have a method inside of a different class that uses the pool concept:

```
public function fetchGroupsInfromation(array $groups) {
    $groupInformationContainer = [];

    $createdRequests           = [];
    $acceptedResponses         = [];
    $rejectedResponses         = [];

    $client                    = new Client();

    foreach($groups as $group) {
        array_push($createdRequests, new Request('GET', $group->types->href));
    }

    $pool = new Pool($client, $createdRequests, [
        'concurrency' => 10,
        'fulfilled'   => function ($response, $index) use (&$acceptedResponses) {
            EveLogHandler::requestLog($response, 'eve_online_group_items_responses.log');

            $groupPagesItterator = new GroupPagesItterator(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()));
            $acceptedResponses[$index] = iterator_to_array($groupPagesItterator->getAllPages());
        },
        'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use(&$rejectedResponses)  {
            array_push($rejectedResponses, $reason);
        },
    ]);

    $promise = $pool->promise();
    $promise->wait();
}
```

I took out some of the other logic inside this method because the main thing I need help with is understanding how to write tests for class methods like these where they use third party services.

The goal is to never hit the API, I have a couple controller tests further up that do that for me (integration tests if you will) How ever I need to test code like this to make sure I get back what I expect. But I feel that if I mock the method or the code inside the method that at that point I am just "spell checking" and I really need to make sure that ok when I pass you this, I ned x back or I need y back.

**So can you guys help me buy maybe giving me some examples, maybe some links to examples on how this type of code would be tested? Some real world stuff?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html) library you could do something like this to create a mock:

```
$response = new Response(); // Create an expected response to return.
$mock = \Mockery::mock('Client[request]');
$mock->shouldReceive('request')->withArgs(['GET', $your_href])->andReturn($reponse);
```

The trick comes in when actually replacing the instance of the `Client` in your code. `new Client()` will always create an instance of the `Client` class, an your mock object will never be used. You have a couple options for this, for one you could pass the `Client` to use.

```
function fetchGroupsInformation(array $groups, $client = null) {
    $client = $client ?: new Client();
    ....
}

fetchGroupsInformation($groups, $mock);
```

Some frameworks have methods for injecting this sort of thing during testing as well. The thing is you don't want to mock the code inside the method you are testing, you want to mock the code being run in a dependency. Replacing the instance of `Client` with something like this allows you code to *think* it called this third-party library and got a return value. Then it handles the return value. This allows you to say that "as long the third-party code works my code does what I expect." It also prevents the call from actually being made. You should test cases that both mock a valid response, and the opposite. For instance if you mock a response with a status 404 does your code respond as expected.

If you didn't write something like `Pool` and are using it from a third-party library, you are at their mercy more or less. Check that they do their own testing. Introducing code that is unstable just makes more work for you.

Comment: This is really good info, the Guzzel library doesn't really test pool inside a real world app more or less that it does as it states. I feel that if I mock the method that uses pool in the above example and say I expect you to return this that all I am doing is testing the spelling and not the actual code of whats going on inside my method (make sense?)

Comment: I think your understanding falls apart at the inclusion of code that doesn't exactly relate to the test. Think about it as though you expect to have a test for the `fetchGroupsInformation()` method which should only examine the lines within the immediate scope. Does this method when given known good parameters have expected results? The large block of code that's passed to the `Pool` constructor is not in the immediate scope of the method being tested. If you want to test that you want a separate test to test that the constructor works. You don't want to test both in the same test.

Comment: Also note that Guzzel **does** test the `Pool` object. See their [source code](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/tests/PoolTest.php). You do have the option of running the included tests yourself, but the author of a third-party application usually does that themselves.

Comment: I know that >.> But how do I test my method that make use of pool with out hitting the api. Do I mock it? and if so how?

Comment: Mocking private methods gets tricky. You'll probably have to mock the `Pool::promise()` method and return a mocked `Promise` that has an expectation for the `wait()` method. It looks like everything after instantiating the `Pool` is code you don't need to test. Your test just really needs to make sure the parameters are being created correctly.

Comment: So in other words mock the method that uses the pool method and say with these params I expect this back .... Should I abstract the pool stuff out to another method or class and mock that so that I can actually call the method its self ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102329/discussion-between-toothlessrebel-and-kyle-adams).

Comment: Sorry it's late here